# discord.py - 'command' is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm new to python and making discord bots so sorry if this is a noob question but I'm stuck.

Been trying to figure it out for hours.

I'm writing a simple bot that will loop through a list of 28 objects and randomly choose 4 of them. Then send those 4 choices into chat so people can vote for their choice.

Last night I was using

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
                return

        if message.content.startswith('!maps'):
                await message.delete()
                channel = client.get_channel(800086126173225010)
                await channel.send('**New poll! Vote below now for tomorrow\'s map!**')
                choice = random.sample(maps,4)

                for x in range(0, 4):

                        mapemp.append(emoji[x]+" - "+choice[x])

                msg = await channel.send('\n\n'.join(mapemp))

                for x in range(0,4):
                
                        await msg.add_reaction(emoji[x]) 
                mapemp.clear()
```

This works fine. But then I found out about `@bot.command` instead of `@client.event` so I'm trying to switch to that. However, when I try to run the command it returns

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Command' object is not iterable`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def maps(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = bot.get_channel(800086126173225010)
    await channel.send('**New poll! Vote below now for tomorrow\'s map!**')
    choice = random.sample(list(maps,4)

    for x in range(0, 4):

            mapemp.append(emoji[x]+" - "+choice[x])

    msg = await channel.send('\n\n'.join(mapemp))

    for x in range(0,4):
    
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji[x])
    mapemp.clear()
```

What makes `@bot.command` so different than `@client.event` that I can't iterate through the choices?

I didnt use to have `random.sample(list(maps,4)` but when I try to run it with just `random.sample(maps,4)` I get a different error.

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).`

So I changed it to `random.sample(list(maps,4)` if that matters.

Comment: Change `random.sample(list(maps,4)` to `random.sample(list(maps,4))`?

Comment: Changed it to `choice = random.sample(list(maps),4)` `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Command' object is not iterable`

`

Comment: When I try `random.sample(list(maps,4))` it returns `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function name and list name are both `maps`. So, when you run `choice = random.sample(list(maps,4)`, it thinks you're referring to the function `maps`, not the list. In order to fix this, you'll either want to

1. Change the name of the function (also changes the name of the command). You can do this by just changing `async def maps(ctx):` to `async def newCommandName(ctx):` (change newCommandName with the new name you want for the function).
2. Change the name of the `maps` list. I don't know where this definition is, but I'll assume it's something like this `maps = []`. Instead of that, you'll want to change the name to something like `mapsList` and then change all references to the list to use `mapsList` instead.

Also, as a side note, `choice = random.sample(list(maps,4)` should be `choice = random.sample(list(maps),4)` instead.